# Function to generate a collection of dataframes (60 days - n days) based on an input dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have written t code to pick a existing dataframe and then randomly generate new dataframes that has some variance of ±20% from the input dataframe. each dataframe must have around 100 rows with 118 columns. The values generated must be unique and even if they are repeated but must be scattered all across the columns but not in the same column. Currently, when I test the below code, it is generating dataframes that has duplicates within each column itself. How to rectify this in the code?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def generate_data(input_df, num_days):
    # Calculate mean and standard deviation for each column
    means = input_df.mean()
    stds = input_df.std()

    for day in range(num_days):
        # Create an empty output dataframe for the current day
        output_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(100), columns=input_df.columns)

        for col in input_df.columns:
            # Calculate lower and upper bounds for random data
            lower_bound = means[col] * (1 - 0.15)
            upper_bound = means[col] * (1 + 0.15)

            # Generate random data based on observed distribution
            np.random.seed(1)
            random_data = np.random.normal(means[col], stds[col], size=100) + np.random.random()

            # Clip data values between lower and upper bounds
            random_data = np.clip(random_data, lower_bound, upper_bound)

            # Assign generated data to output dataframe
            output_df[col] = random_data

        # Generate a unique file name for the current day using timestamp
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        file_name = "D:\pycdf" + "\\" + f"generated_data_{day + 1}_{timestamp}.csv"

        # Save the dataframe for the current day as CSV
        output_df.to_csv(file_name, index=False)

        print(f"Dataframe for Day {day + 1} saved as: {file_name}")

input_df = ldf.copy(deep=True)

num_days = 4
generate_data(input_df, num_days)
```

The above code is able to generate a dataframes for each of the days. I tried to generate for 4 days.
Each day, the dataframe that is generated has duplicate values within the same column itself. I would want to have unique set of values. Even if it duplicates the value, it can have it in some ohter column but not in the same column

Comment: Do you have the data/code to load/generate `ldf`?

Comment: code is the same function i wrote above. data is any input dataframe that has a set of columns that can have floating point values.